# Flash, autoplay IE issue

Tags: flash

I have a weird situation.

I have a flash fine and in IE7/8 the flash doesn't have auto play bu default when I refresh the page. When I click right click check "play" the flash is starting.

I even force :

```
var params = {
            play: "true",
            loop:"true"
        };
```

with No success.

On FF/Ie9/Chrome works fine .

Did someone had this issue before  and knows how to fix ?

Thanks !

Comment: IE7 has a client-side option that blocks auto-play (much like Opera). Don't know about IE8 though.

Comment: Hi, did you find something regarding this issue? I have exactly the same problem and I didn't find any solution yet :(

Comment: I've discovered something :) Try to upload your swf to another domain. I uploaded my own and with this domain it works fine. So the the problem is domain-wide, but I don't know yet what is exactly :)